# Javascript increase [i] when checkbox == true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to give IDs to divs from checkboxes which **only** are checked. E.g. I got 5 checkboxes and every time a checkbox has not been checked the loop should increase all upcoming checked checkboxes by 1.

```js
function saveData() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('cb')[i].id = 'id' +i;
        let id_active = document.getElementById('id' + i);
        if (id_active.checked === true) {
            let div_id = document.getElementsByClassName('div')[i].id = 'div' + i;
            document.getElementsByClassName('div')[i].innerText = div_id;
            
        } 
        if (id_active.checked === false) {
            i += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb">
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" checked="">
<input type="checkbox" class="cb">
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="saveData()">Check</button>


<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
```

So in this case the third div should get the id="4" but the loop stops after a checkbox is not checked. How can I increase i + 1 for all upcoming [i] and don't stop the loop after the first `checkbox.checked === false`?
A result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: with each `id_active.checked === false` your loop skips one iteration and so on, so you need another variable to manipulate rather than the `i` variable which is used to loop over the elements

Comment: "*So in this case the third div should get the `id="4"`...*" - can you show us the HTML that should result from the function, rather than trying to describe it?

Comment: @SaymoinSam can you give me an example what extra variable I need?

Comment: Its not really clear to me what you want to achieve but `id_active` will always be undefined because there is no element with the id `id#`

Comment: @MarkBaijens Checkbox 1,2 and 4 are checked. Checkbox 3 not. I want the number of the checked checkboxes to be the ID of the divs below. U understand? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @SaymoinSam can you give me an example what extra variable I need?

I meant something like this, note that I have refactored your code to a better and clean code

```js
function saveData() {
  let divs = document.querySelectorAll(".div"), index = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll(".cb").forEach(function(input, ind) {
    if(input.checked) {
      divs[index].id = divs[index++].innerText = `div${ind}`;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb">
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" checked="">
<input type="checkbox" class="cb">
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="saveData()">Check</button>


<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
```

Comment: the problem that wasn't solved in your answer is that where there are less divs, you are getting an error

Comment: @FlashThunder The OP didn't say anything about that and he's making the same number of div elements as the number of the checked inputs statically, if he wants a dynamic solution to generate div elements according to the number of checked input elements then he needs just to ask and I will modify my answer to do that

Comment: still your script fails if you will check 4 checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

This is result I think you are wanting. You need a second counter.

```
function saveData() {
        let j=0;
        for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            document.getElementsByClassName('cb')[i].id = 'cb'+ i;
            let id_active = document.getElementById('cb' + i);
            if (id_active.checked === true) {
                let div_id = document.getElementsByClassName('cb')[i].id;
                console.log(div_id);
                document.getElementsByClassName('div')[j].innerText = div_id;
                j+=1;
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function saveData() {
    let divs = $('.div');
    let checkboxes = $('.cb');
    let j = 0;
    $(divs).removeAttr('id',"");
    $(checkboxes).each(function(i){
       if($(this).is(':checked') && $(divs).get(j)){
          $(divs[j]).attr('id','div'+i);
          j++;
       }
    });
    $(divs).each(function(i){
       $(this).text('div' + i + ' has id: ' + $(this).attr('id'));
    });
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<input type="checkbox" class="cb" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb">
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" checked="">
<input type="checkbox" class="cb">
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="saveData()">Check</button>


<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
```